# Spring AMQP Responding to ReplyTo Queue from MessageListener

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, amqp

If I am asynchronously listening to Spring AMQP messages how do I respond using the ReplyTo Queue and Correlation ID provided by the sender?

```
    @Override
public void onMessage(Message message) {

    byte[] bytes = message.getBody();

    String body = new String (bytes);

    logger.info(application + " processing message: \n" + body);

    //some business logic

    //now I want to respond to the replyto queue with the correlation ID
    //rabbitTemplate.????

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on the helpful feedback here is the equivalent solution using Spring Messaging:

```
public void onMessage(Message message) {

//mock response body
String body = "{ \"processing\": \"123456789\"}";

//mock response properties
MessageProperties properties = new MessageProperties();
properties.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.toString());
properties.setContentEncoding(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());       

//return the Correlation ID if present
if (message.getMessageProperties().getCorrelationId() != null) {

    properties.setCorrelationId(message.getMessageProperties().getCorrelationId());
}

//create and return the response message
Message responseMessage = new Message(body.getBytes(), properties);

rabbitTemplate.send(message.getMessageProperties().getReplyTo(), responseMessage);

logger.info("Processed and returned message");
```

}

The confusing part for someone new to AMQP is knowing that the reply-to message property is the "Routing Key" value when replying (send or convertAndSend methods). And that temporary queues are created in the default exchange. This is not always the case with a permanent reply-to queue which would require a correlation-id (not necessary with temp reply-to queue).

Answer (score 0):

One work-around I found was to extend ChannelAwareMessageListener and constructing the response as follows

```
@Override
public void onMessage(Message message, Channel channel) {

    String body = new String (message.getBody());

    String correlationId = new String (message.getMessageProperties().getCorrelationId());

    String replyTo = new String (message.getMessageProperties().getReplyTo());

    logger.info("Processing message with Correlation ID : " 
            + correlationId + " Replying To: " + replyTo + " and Message: \n"
            + body);

    BasicProperties basicProperties = new BasicProperties
            .Builder()
            .correlationId(correlationId)
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.getType())
            .contentEncoding(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name())
            .build();

    String response = "{\"response\":" + body + "}";

    try {

        channel.basicPublish( "", replyTo, basicProperties, response.getBytes());

    } catch (IOException e) {

        logger.error("Failed to send message: \n" + e.getMessage());
    }

    logger.info("Processed Message");
}
```

This works fine but it would be great if I could respond similarly using the RabbitMQTemplate.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply call [AmqpTemplate.send(routingKey, message)](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/api/org/springframework/amqp/core/AmqpTemplate.html#send-java.lang.String-org.springframework.amqp.core.Message-).

As a routing key use the *reply-to* value. The template will publish to the default exchange and route the message to the queue specified as a *routing key* (which is your reply-to queue).

Also, you may want set the *correlation id* if the other side is doing request-reponse, so the response could be matched with request.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The routing key parameter in the send methods was really throwing me off in this scenario. Do you know if the reply-to is also used in the routing key value for the send methods in the rabbitTemplate?

Comment: Only if you publish to the default exchange (as the `send` method does in the example above). If you publish to specific exchange, then the message is routed according to the bindings. For more info, take a look at https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/amqp-concepts.html